# Scala: Unable to get intellisense of "productIterator" in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

I am pretty new in Scala. When i want to iterate a tuple using "productIterator", eclipse not showing any **intellisense**. But typing exactly, code is working no compilation error. ***What is wrong with intellisense?*** Thanks in Advance.

**Here is my code Ex:**

```
val t = (4, 3, 2, 5) 
t.productIterator.foreach{ i =>println("Value = " + i )}
```